# How to calculate monthly return on a changing capital base when swing trading?

Tags: trading, capital-gain, rate-of-return

I'm just starting out in swing trading, and I'm facing a somewhat nagging doubt. Since last January I executed 27 trades, with varying results. I am tracking down the percent return on each trade along with a bunch of other parameters, such as the trade cost, commissions, entry and exit price, entry and exit date etc.

My question is this: how in the world can I calculate, by the end of this year, my yearly percent return of my trading activity? I cannot figure out what the base capital should be, since it varies with time. I started with a certain sum but I kept adding some every now and then from my bank account...any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method would be to take note of the value of all your holdings each time you trade.  Then you have simple returns from one trade to the next over your whole portfolio.

Example calculation here: https://money.stackexchange.com/a/98132/11768