# Calculating return - mix of ROI and TWR

Tags: investing, rate-of-return

I've got a portfolio with a mix of buy and total sell and some with a mix of buy and partial sell.

For the buy and total sell, a simple ROI calculation will work BUT given there are also a mix of buy and partial sell TWR seems to make sense.

However, the ROI and the TWR calculation aren't matching up?

```
Opening deposit = $1081.04
Full sale       = $964.47
Earnt           = $-116.57
ROI             = -10.8%

Opening deposit = $2091.11
Full sale       = $1746.55
Earnt           = $-344.56
ROI             = -16.5%

Combining both = ($-116.57 + $-344.56)/($1081.04 + $2091.11) 
               = -14.5%

Where-as a Time Weighted Return = ((1+ -10.8%) * (1+ -16.5%)) - 1
                                = -25.5%
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The time-weighted return implies you made two consecutive investments, whereas the ROI implies two simultaneous investments.

Comment: Yep - but is there anyway to combine these? I'll have a mix of both for a certain asset and want to get the overall return %

Comment: One method is shown [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/98132/11768).  Do ask if there are any points you are unclear on.  It involves calculating the ROI for each unique timespan-mix of investments, then combining them by TWR.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisDegnen

Lost me a little with the references in that

I get calculating the ROI for each unique timespan-mix of investments - that's ok.

That method then divides the above ROI by timespan by the number of days in between?

And for each time period, SUM what the portfolio is worth at that time period DIVIDED by what it was worth last period... ultimately multiplying all those resulting percentages together?

Comment: Sounds right. A timespan for each mix of investments. A single investment's total ROI can be divided by finding the daily rate: `daily = (1 + roi)^(1/alldays) - 1` and then compounded for the required timespan: `spanROI = (1 + daily)^lessdays) - 1`.  Then the combined ROI for the timespan can be calculated and used in the TWR.